# Extract value between $ and < in line of text using sed or alternative function

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I'm trying to extract the price from this line:

```
<div class="bpi-value bpiUSD">$634.17</div>
```

I would like to output:

```
634.17
```

I've tried:

```
sed -n "/$/,/</p"
```

In the hope of extracting everything between the `$` and the `<` but it isn't working. I'm thinking the reason for this may be that the dollar sign is being interpreted as a variable or something else. What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: with grep and pcre `echo '<div class="bpi-value bpiUSD">$634.17</div>' | grep -oP '\$\K[^<]+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed handles regular expressions and the '$' means "end of line". The shortest sed line that will work (assuming your lines are well behaved)

```
$ echo '<div class="bpi-value bpiUSD">$634.17</div>' | sed 's/.*\$\(.*\)<.*/\1/'
634.17
```

Comment: In the backslash in `\$` needed?

Comment: Yes, you have to escape the '$' or else it is treated like the end of line.

Answer (score 3):

The Right Way to extract content from markup languages is using syntax-aware tools:

```
read -r var < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//div[@class="bpi-value bpiUSD"]' -v . <in.xhtml)
var=${var#'$'} # strip leading $
```

However, if you *must*, and you're processing only a single line, use bash's native [built-in string manipulation primitives](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) rather than paying startup cost for an external tool such as `sed`:

```
line='<div class="bpi-value bpiUSD">$634.17</div>'
var=${line#*$}   # delete everything up and including to first $
var=${var%%'<'*} # delete everything after the first remaining <
```

---

See also:

- [The bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) (the specific string-manipulation syntax used above).
- [The Wooledge BashGuide on paramater expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Biffen.  However, if your lines are fixed-format,

```
sed 's/^[^$]\+\(\$[0-9.]\{1,\}\).*$/\1/' <input filename>
```

should do it.  It skips to the `$` (`\$` in sed), keeps the `$` followed by digits or periods (`\(\$[0-9.]\{1,\}\)`), and then clears out to the end.  Tested on GNU sed 4.2.2 in bash.

(**fixed**) the first version of this answer didn't have enough backslashes.

Comment: Being able to access ERE features in BRE by adding backslashes is a GNU extension. Might want to stick to pure BRE if portability is a goal, or use `sed -r` (GNU) / `sed -E` (BSD) and use ERE explicitly.